# Getting items to disappear and reappear from text area using check boxes

Tags: java, swing

What I am trying to do with this program is get a pane to pop up with options for a dorm "private room, cable, internet" and so on. As the user click each check box to signify they want the option. I want the options to disappear from the text area.

So far I have gotten the list to appear when the program is run, and the check boxes to append the output however it now just removes everything but what I clicked and then adds options as I click the different boxes.

I am not really sure what else I can do. 
Can you help?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JDormRoom extends JFrame implements ItemListener {

    FlowLayout flow = new FlowLayout();
    JCheckBox privateRm = new JCheckBox("Private");
    JCheckBox internet = new JCheckBox("Internet");
    JCheckBox cable = new JCheckBox("Cable TV");
    JCheckBox microwave = new JCheckBox("Microwave");
    JCheckBox refrigerator = new JCheckBox("Refrigerator");
    JTextArea outArea = new JTextArea("Private Room" 
                            + "\nInternet" + "\nCable" 
                            +"\nMicrowave" + "\nRefrigerator", 30,30);
    String dormOption = "";
    String output = "";

    public JDormRoom() {
        super("Check Box");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(flow);
        pane.add(privateRm);
        privateRm.addItemListener(this);
        pane.add(internet);
        internet.addItemListener(this);
        pane.add(cable);
        cable.addItemListener(this);
        pane.add(microwave);
        microwave.addItemListener(this);
        pane.add(refrigerator);
        refrigerator.addItemListener(this);
        pane.add(outArea);
        setContentPane(pane);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        JDormRoom dFrame = new JDormRoom();
        dFrame.setSize(450,300);
        dFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent check) {
        Object source = check.getItem();
        int select = check.getStateChange();
        if (source == privateRm) {
            //int select = check.getStateChange();
            if (privateRm.isSelected())
                if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {           
                    dormOption = "Private Room\n";
                    output += dormOption;
                }
        }
        if (source == internet) {
            //int select = check.getStateChange();
            if (internet.isSelected())
                if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {           
                    dormOption = "Internet\n";
                    output += dormOption;
                }
        }
        if (source == cable) {
            //int select = check.getStateChange();
            if (cable.isSelected())
                if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {           
                    dormOption = "Cable TV\n";
                    output += dormOption;
                }
        }
        if (source == microwave) {
            //int select = check.getStateChange();
            if (microwave.isSelected())
                if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {           
                    dormOption = "Microwave\n";
                    output += dormOption;
                }
        }
        if (source == refrigerator) {
            //int select = check.getStateChange();
            if (refrigerator.isSelected())
                if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {           
                    dormOption = "Refrigerator\n";
                    output += dormOption;
                }
        }
        outArea.setText(output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don' think you really need to check the source of the event, simply check the `isSelected` state of each `JCheckBox`. Also, I don't think `if(select == ItemEvent.SELECTED)` is adding any value.  Instead, I'd consider just using a `ActionListener`

Comment: See now thats the thing I can't figure out how to check the `isSelected` state of the check boxes. @MadProgrammer

Comment: But you are, `cable.isSelected()` ... just use an `ActionListener` instead

Comment: I don't think a text area is what you want since you can't manage the items there well. Maybe a `JList`?

Comment: On the `selected` check, why not set it `invisible`, if that is what you need?